# Make DIV max-height equal to `window height - 100px`

Tags: css

There is a way to set `max-height` in `%`, but is here any way  to set DIV max-height, so it would be 100px smaller than window height with only CSS?

It must not be a fixed layout, user must be able to scroll page vertically, but DIV always should be resized to `window height - 100px`. Is this possible, or will I have to use JS for that?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Yes:

```
#specificElement {
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This uses the CSS `calc()` function to subtract `100px` from  `100vh` (`1vh` being one percent of the view-port's height) and uses the result as the value of the `height` property.

The `box-sizing` forces the browser to include `padding`, and `border`s, in the calculated `height` of the element.

Obviously use a relevant selector for your use-case.

References:

- [`calc()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc).
- [CSS lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths).

Comment: it is not working if I use calc(100vh-100px) instead of calc(100vh - 100px). Hope, it helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

`#specificElement {
  height: calc(100vh - 100%);
  min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}`

set min height so that your dyanmic content should not get effect and give height in percentage for dymanic result.